# Bring line to top in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, android-canvas, z-index, mpandroidchart

Am drawing 3 lines in [MPAndroidChart's](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) **LineChart**.
[image: MPAndroidChart's Graph]

```
drawBlueLine();
drawGreenLine();
drawRedLine();
```

Line drawn first ***(blue)*** is at the bottom. How to bring it above `Red`.

Is there any API similar to below?

```
mBlueChart.setZIndex(10);
mBlueChart.bringToTop();
mBlueChart.bringToFront();
```

***Not adding code as this relates to API.***

**EDIT:** am in a situation where I have to push **blue line first**.

Comment: What happens if you change the order of the `draw` functions?

Comment: @admdrew The order does change. But, am in a situation where I have to push blue line first.

Comment: Is `mBlueChart` a `LineChartItem` object?

Comment: `LineChart mBlueChart;`

Comment: *Why* can't you draw `mBlueChart` first? From what I can tell, the library support changing of a z-index. Either report a bug, make a change yourself, or change the draw order.

Comment: **Why can't you draw mBlueChart first?**. Am drawing more than 100 lines & I have setting specific to BlueLine, like `circleSize` If I try to draw it at last, I have to check every time if my current line is last which is not good way to go. Also it needs lot of code change, since chart is created while drawing BlueLine. ***Which leaves me to [increase z-index](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/249)***

Comment: Can you draw `mBlueChart` twice? First time, before all the other lines, then second time after the last?

Comment: Nope, if so then `X-axis` label will be duplicated at first & last position.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?